# The name "NewBitmap" does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am trying to make to put adjust brightness thing but I am getting does not exist in current context error for "NewBitmap" in this code

```
picBox.Image = AdjustBrightness(NewBitmap, trackBar1.Value);
```

Here is my code

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblBrightNum.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
        picBox.Image = AdjustBrightness(NewBitmap, trackBar1.Value);
    }



 public static Bitmap AdjustBrightness(Bitmap Image, int Value)
    {
        Bitmap TempBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.Clone();
        float FinalValue = (float)Value / 255.0f;
        Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height);
        Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap);
        float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={
                  new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                  new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                  new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                  new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                  new float[] {FinalValue, FinalValue, FinalValue, 1, 1}
             };

        ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(FloatColorMatrix);
        ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes();
        Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);
        NewGraphics.DrawImage(TempBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height), 0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Attributes);
        Attributes.Dispose();
        NewGraphics.Dispose();
        return NewBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: It's because you're passing it into `AdjustBrightness`, where it's out of scope. Did you mean to pass in `picBox.Image` instead?

Comment: I didnt get your point there.

Comment: In `trackBar1_Scroll`, you try to pass `NewBitmap` into `AdjustBrightness`, but you haven't declared it. It looks to me like you're trying to adjust the brightness of the image in `picBox`, which would mean you should pass in `picBox.Image` instead of `NewBitmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program mainly contains two methods, one is     trackBar1_Scroll, another one is AdjustBrightness, visual studio knows what is "NewBitmap" in the AdjustBrightness method, but it doesn't know what is "NewBitmap" in the trackBar1_Scroll

```
 private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblBrightNum.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
            //Visual studio is complaining about this, you haven't define "NewBitmap", you can fix by adding below:
            Bitmap NewBitmap = //your bitmap
            picBox.Image = AdjustBrightness(NewBitmap, trackBar1.Value);
        }



     public static Bitmap AdjustBrightness(Bitmap Image, int Value)
        {
            Bitmap TempBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.Clone();
            float FinalValue = (float)Value / 255.0f;
            Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height);
            Graphics NewGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(NewBitmap);
            float[][] FloatColorMatrix ={
                      new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                      new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                      new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                      new float[] {FinalValue, FinalValue, FinalValue, 1, 1}
                 };

            ColorMatrix NewColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(FloatColorMatrix);
            ImageAttributes Attributes = new ImageAttributes();
            Attributes.SetColorMatrix(NewColorMatrix);
            NewGraphics.DrawImage(TempBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height), 0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Attributes);
            Attributes.Dispose();
            NewGraphics.Dispose();
            return NewBitmap;
```